# .htaccess redirect folder to folder exact match

Tags: .htaccess

Ok, i'm trying to redirect a language that is written as a folder something like so:

```
RedirectMatch 301 ^index.php/es$ index.php/en
```

As you can see I only want it to redirect when it is an exact match to index.php/es so index.php/es/inicio would not redirect.

It just won't work for me I have tried several variations.

This must be independent of domain name as I have multiple domains pointing at this site that all need to use this rule.

Comment: is it not redirecting at all, or is it redirecting for all variations?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing some leading slashes:

```
RedirectMatch 301 ^/index.php/es$ /index.php/en
```

The URI put through the redirect/redirectmatch statements have a leading slash, so `^index.php/es$` would never match.

Comment: That's great, but just noticed I need for it to have an optional ending slash so es/ or just es

Comment: @traxwriter Then `^/index.php/es/?$`